# Postgresql triggers - using the value you just inserted

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have the following problem regarding triggers :

```
IF condition THEN
  INSERT INTO table1(colID,col2,col3) VALUES (currval(a),b,NEW."ID")
ELSE
  INTO table table2(coll1,coll2) VALUES (a,NEW."ID")
```

I import more entries at the same time in my database, the first goes into the the "if" condition and the rest of the entries go in "else" condition. In the else I want to use the a value(the ID) I inserted, but Postgres doesn't seem to know that value until I save (using my front end app). How can i call that value before saving (I tried before insert, after insert...)? 
The idea is that i want to insert an entry and create the connections with other tables and the rest of the entries just need to be connected to the same rows(entries) from other tables.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you try `NEW.a` ?

Comment: Does this trigger happen `BEFORE UPDATE` or `AFTER UPDATE`? Have you tried `AFTER`?